# Can we make Emacs find the definition of the variable?

Tags: java, emacs

I try to learn to use Emacs as my programming editor. I use it to edit Java. Now, let say i have this code :

```
 
 private Sprite logo = null;//1                                                                                                


    private void createSprites(){//2
        logo = new ASprite();//3

    }//4
```

and now my cursor is in the word logo at line 3. How can I jump quickly to logo definition at line 1? All I know is C-s, C-r. .. but then I have to type logo, not directly find logo definition.

Thank you

EDITED:
I just using semantic-mode on Emacs 2.2 : I can jump to a definition of a tag (function, variable) using `C-c , j` This solve my problem :)

Comment: Get a real Java IDE. IntelliJ free version. I must advise against your using emacs even if it's not polite, just like we must save a person from suicide against his free will. You are literally killing your life if you don't use IDE for Java programming.

Comment: Basically, I already using Netbeans for, say, 3 years and also Eclipse. Currently my job here let me freely choose editor (not IDE) that I like, because we are using our own building system. I think Emacs will nicely fit into my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by building a TAGS file containing the needed information by using for example [exuberant-ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) or Etags that should already be installed. In order to generate the TAGS file you can use:

```
exuberant-ctags -e -R --language-force=java /opt/sun-jdk-1.5.0.08/share/
```

Once done, and your cursor is on the "logo"  string, press <kbd>M-.</kbd> ( and emacs will ask you for the  TAGS file. Enter the location to it and it will find the definition of the variable.

Comment: I'll try it. But, isn't that M-x . means entering emacs command line?

Comment: Owh, I am sorry. I mean, when we press M-x (that is ALT-x in my Windows), isnt' it  emacs will prompt for a command ??? that's what I mean :)

Comment: @swdev: Yes, it's <kbd>M-.</kbd>, not <kbd>M-x .</kbd>.

Comment: Yes, a small misstype there, it should be M . and not M-x .

Comment: Yup. I just realize it was a typho, when I read about jump to tag (M-.)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the emacs java-mode is actually building up an internal syntax tree to make these kinds of searches possible.
Eclipse is the world-champion here. 
The good think is: Eclipse comes with a Emacs key-bindings, so you will feel right at home.

C-x C-c

Comment: I don't think the key bindings are the primary reason people use emacs.

Comment: yes, indeed. I like the environemnt here in Emacs, where (off course this is subjective) all I see is one Emacs black screen and there you see the code printed out just well.

Comment: I never said that is the primary reason, but Eclipse supporting those make a transition easy. And if one window is your desire, you can pretty much lay out all the windows of Eclipse in any way you want. I wrote my fair share of elisp code, but going somewhere near the feature set of Eclipse is madness